# Subquery example helping

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I have a problem for `SUM`

**Table:**

```
ID     date        type price limit
1   01/02/2016      1     10    3
2   02/02/2016      1     15    2
3   03/02/2016      1     10    0
4   01/02/2016      2     10    2
5   02/02/2016      2     20    2
6   03/02/2016      2     30    2

$sql = SELECT type,SUM(price) as total from table **where limit>0**  GROUP BY type
```

Normaly it will return:

```
1 35
2 60
```

But I need, if type 1 have any zero limit don't calculate.

```
***2 60***
```

Di I need to use a sub query?

Comment: using sub query is not recommended, as it slows down your result retrieval..

Comment: limit is a reserved word. Make sure you escape it in query \`limit\`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT `type`, SUM(price) AS total 
FROM table   
GROUP BY `type`
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN `limit` = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The `HAVING` clause will filter out any `type` groups that contain at least one `limit=0` rows.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5deae6/2)

Comment: doubt it - sounds like OP wants to exclude the entire grouping if any member records have limit=0.

Comment: Giorgos Betsos Thank You So Much.

Comment: @MURATAYDIN Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mask this, or any other answer, as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.